# Specifying a property source based on an active profile in a Springboot application

Tags: spring-boot

When using a Property class in a Springboot application to hold certain configuration properties the path to a specific property file can be specified using:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:services/service-**${spring.profiles.active}**.properties")
public class MuPropertiesConfig {...
```

The problem is when I have multiple active profiles.
The names of the profiles are being concatenated resulting in a FileNotFound Exception when the application is started with multiple profiles.

What can I use in the "$"-paceholder in the @PropertySource placeholder?
Is there some kind of EL I can use?
For instance can I loop over the profiles and if the profile is dev, test, acc or prod then use the classpath:services/service-${specific-profile}.properties?

Comment: Don't. Specif the `spring.config.additional-locations` and Spring Boot will automatically load the files, don't work around that.

Comment: But if I want to use the first active profile in the @PropertySource annotation how do I do that? I get the feeling that it is not possible since the spring.profiles.active property is a concatenated string value. Is there a placeholder for the first profile?

Comment: No there isn't. It also isn't a concatenated value it is actually a `String[]`. Nonetheless use the Spring Boot provided feature and it will load your file for you.